# is it possible to make it so that the executable made by pyinstaller does not close when it run sucessfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I made a python terminal program for windows and I want it to work in the same way it would work if we were using the Linux terminal. I want the file to finish successfully without adding something  like an infinite loop because that could make it impossible to work on my specific python program but I want the executable not to close. My program displays a text that tells the user that everything is OK at the end of the program.

I tried using an infinite loop but I have a problem with the open statement in python with the write mode. if the program doesn't terminate, the text that I want to write doesn't appear until the program finishes for some reason(at least with the executable made by Pyinstaller)

Comment: You can add an `input` at the end of the code.

Comment: Not completely clear what you try to achieve. _the same way it would work if we were using the Linux terminal_ - do you mean not to close the terminal window when the program ends? If you open `cmd` and run the program, the window will not close when the program finish. Or you can use `input()` and wait for user input before finishing the program

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very straightforward.

Instead of using print, use input:

```
input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Comment: yeah, that's the solution I came up with but it would be nice if program ended but the terminal didn't close so they didn't have to press 'enter". Thank you for the response

Comment: Do you mean that the terminal should not be closed under any circumstances?

Comment: yeah, and I don't want the user to manually open the cmd terminal in order for that to happen